# Ubuntu Server 18.10 Root on SSD with ZFS

Tags: server, ssd, zfs

I would like to move my Ubuntu Server 18.10 installation onto ZFS on an SSD, namely a Samsung 970 EVO.

I have read [Ubuntu 18.04 Root on ZFS](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS) on the `zfsonlinux/zfs` wiki. This document outlines the following system requirements:

> - Ubuntu 18.04.1 ("Bionic") Desktop CD **(not any server images)**
> - A drive which presents **512B logical sectors**. Installing on a drive which presents 4KiB logical sectors (a “4Kn” drive) should work with UEFI partitioning, but this has not been tested.

This leads to the following two questions:

1. Why is this restricted to the Ubuntu Desktop?
2. Given that `cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/hw_sector_size` returns `512`, am I save to proceed?
3. `ZFSonLinux` does not support **`Trim`** yet. Will this be a problem? If yes, is there a way to mitigate this problem?